# Check if DOM associated with current ViewModel is displayed?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a following use case:

- I'm creating Knockout custom component:

  ```
  ko.components.register("detail", {
      template: {require: "text!components/detail.html"},
      viewModel: DetailViewModel
  });
  ```
- Inside the `DetailViewModel`, I'm performing some e.g. XHR that takes 60 seconds to finish. In case the XHR fails, I'm showing user a notification about it.

Now my problem is that the XHR takes 60 seconds and while it is still "pending", user navigates to a page that no longer contains the "detail" component and then the XHR fails. I don't want to show any notification in this case, simply because there is no use to show failure notification if the original component is no longer displayed.

Is there a way to determine inside the `DetailViewModel` function if the associated DOM element is still "present" on page? Right now I'm using some custom defined property of the VM ("`isVisible`") and changing the property to `false` in `DetailViewModel.prototype.dispose`, but I was wondering if there is a easier/cleaner way to do that without declaring any custom property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "createViewModel" handler in the component registration, which receives componentInfo as a second argument. "componentInfo.element" is a component's DOMElement. So you can access it and check it's visibility.

```
ko.components.register('detail', {
    viewModel: {
        createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
            var domElement = componentInfo.element;
            // You can pass domElement as a parameter for the DetailViewModel
            return new DetailViewModel(params);
        }
    },
    template: {require: "text!components/detail.html"}
});
```